# Spring MVC cast principal object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I currently do the following in my Spring MVC project alot:

```
protected String onSubmit(UploadMessagesCommand command, Principal principal) throws Exception {
    MyCustomUserDetailsImpl user = (MyCustomUserDetailsImpl) principal;
    //etc
}
```

Is there a better way of getting this to work, so I can replace the principal argument with a user argument and avoid the cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resiliently noticed that you can use the User(Details) directly.

```
protected String onSubmit(UploadMessagesCommand command, User user) throws Exception {
   //etc
}
```